# Incorrect use of a property or a bad init method?

Tags: objective-c

I'm not sure I'm using the property function correctly.

```
@synthesize generated;

-(id)initWithNumber:(int)FirstNumber toSecond:(int)SecondNumber;
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        generated = FirstNumber + SecondNumber;
    }
    return self;
}
```

The property `generated` is just an `int`. Shouldn't I be able to use a property as a global value that I can access?
Is that a valid `init` method?

Comment: Where and how did you declare your property?

Comment: self.generated = FirstNumber + SecondNumber;

Comment: @Stas I used '@property int generated;'

Comment: I mean where is your `@property..`?

Comment: @Stas In the class .h file (The property method is in the Addtogether.h, the code in the original question is in the Addtogether.m implementation file)

Comment: Ok, so answers are below (: Good luck!

Comment: I think you can only initialize objects with @property and int is a primitive type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use properties with a `self.` qualifier.
just replace `generated = FirstNumber + SecondNumber;` with

```
self.generated = FirstNumber + SecondNumber;
```

Comment: Thats what I was thinking but I still get a breakpoint at the self.generated line. I used '@property int generated;' in my header file

Comment: @DeepakBhalla It doesn't matter. You import your header file, so all declarations are visible in .m Note, that if you declare property or method in .m file, it will be __private__ and if you declare it in .h it will be __public__

Answer (score 3):

You got two choices:

1) `self.generated  = FirstNumber  + SecondNumber;`

2)

```
_generated = FirstNumber + SecondNumber;
```

Comment: It's important to note that the second version will _not_ result in any observers of the property being informed of a value change. Which does make sense, as the observation is on the property, not the underlying value. The complexities of key-value coding...